# Using jQuery objects in jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors, selector, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery, and think I might be making something harder than it needs to be. I've got a jQuery variable that is just an unordered list. It was declared this way:

```
var $list = $('#activityList'); // activityList is ID of <ul>
```

I'm trying to select all `<li>` elements within that list using the variable I've created:

```
$items = $('#' + $list.attr('id') + ' > li');
```

Does anyone know if there's a different syntax to achieve the same thing without having to break the variable down to it's id attribute?

Thanks.

**Clarification:** I used simplified code for the purposes of asking the question, but I do want to make use of the jQuery variable "$list" within the selector, rather than hardcoding the ID.

Comment: why do you prefix your variables with $?

Comment: Because it makes it easier to identify jQuery objects withing a large block of js code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$items = $('li', $list);
```

That should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Should actually be $('li', $list) - no # before the li. :)

Comment: Also worth noting that you can pass either a jQuery object or a DOM object as the context.

Comment: Now will this answer get me only the `li` elements that are direct descendants, or will it retrieve all ancestors? What if I did this: `$items = $('> li', $list)`. Would that work?

Comment: It will select items just like the normal context EXCEPT it will be filtered to only children and decendents of the *context*

Comment: also, `$list.find('li')` is equivalent

Answer (score 3):

$("#activitylist > li") would work, as > traverses content.  You can also use, with $list as a JQuery object:

$list.find("li") or $list.children("li") to find the list items as well.  children would be more efficient if you are only looking for immediate children.

Comment: +1 for find/children as it is functionality equivilant to the dominant answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var items = $('#activityList > li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what's wrong with...

```
var $items = $('#activityList > li');
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, you just already **have** the context to search in (`$list`) so why not save some processing and start there? ;)